# Determine method success when the return value is not a boolean

Tags: java, language-agnostic, control-flow

When programming I try to modularize my code into as small and focused methods as possible, sometimes this becomes a problem because if I am in some I/O loop and some method fails to get the requested data then I can't just control the flow of the return value with ease like I could if I had one big method.

Most methods remedy this by returning a boolean indicating success, but my question is, what is the best practice when it comes to success/failure of a method which returns an important object?

Consider the following java code:

```
public JSONObject toJSONObjectForServer() { 
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put(KEY_TASKTYPE, _taskType);
        jsonObject.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, _timestamp);
        jsonObject.put(KEY_TASKSCORE, _taskScore);
        jsonObject.put(KEY_UNITSCONSUMED, _unitsConsumed);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

If this fails for some reason, an empty JSONObject would be returned. deferring the error detection to the calling method, making me have to write ugly stuff like:

```
JSONObject result = x.toJSONObjectForServer();
    if (result.has(KEY_TASKTYPE))
         // method success
    else // method failure
```

Handling results in such a way is not self-explanatory. I could define a new class for every return type:

```
public class JSONObjectForServerResult { 
    private JSONObject _object;
    private boolean _result;

    public JSONObject getObject { return _object; }
    public boolean getResult { return _result; } 

    // ctor
}
```

and then have the caller like this:

```
    // some method
    JSONObjectForServerResult forServerResult = x.toJSONObjectForServer();
    if (forServerResult.getResult())
         // method success
    else // method failure
```

But this seems convoluted and a lot of work.

Is there something I am missing when it comes to control flow/error handling in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: If you get any exception in your method area initialize your object to null ex:`jsonObject = null;` in catch block. finally method return null object. then you check once again before the `if block` (as you mentioned above) result is null or not if it is null then method execution/logic will failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as the other answer suggested, simply use exception handling to signal when something went wrong and there is no result.  This is in fact what exceptions were designed for.

However, in some languages, including Java 8, there is mechanism similar to what you're proposing as a "new class for every return type", but done generically, so that you don't have to code it yourself and you don't need a new one for every type.

In Haskell, this is the [Maybe monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html).  In Scala it is [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Option), and in 
Java 8, it is [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: I feel like I have so much power now! Thanks for the informative answer!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are catching the exception in the first place. Can you not throw the JSONException and let the caller deal with the error?

Comment: I could but the example I've given is just a general example of a common problem I encounter. For example, what if it wasn't a try catch but an I/O network operation, where the bytes received doesn't match what is expected? An exception is not thrown by the system. Is the solution simply to throw exceptions to the caller? I was taught in uni to try not to throw exceptions if you can help it.

Comment: But I think the answer is the same. You should use Exceptions as they are intended; for exceptions.  By catching the error you're hiding the real state from the calling code, which then has to work out what actually happened, resulting in 'ugly stuff'.

Comment: And I think you should go back to whoever told you not to throw exceptions and ask them why. They are extremely useful.

Comment: I know it seems like a silly question but I agree that exceptions are perfect in this situation. It's actually something we was taught by a number of lecturers.